# Objective-J Tutorial

Tags: objective-j

Is learning Objective-J worth it, considering the limited number of Objective-J tutorials? Also, what would be a good place to start?

Comment: according to the wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-J you could learn objective C (which is similar to J) which would be enough tutorials for a starting place.

Comment: Would you mind saying what the current tutorials are missing so that we can put a better one together?

Comment: How does lack of tutorials make something not worth learning? It just makes it (at most) a bit harder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-J is used primarily with the Cappuccino framework. They have some [tutorials](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/objective-j-tutorial.php) on their site.